# /usr/bin/sshd isn't linked against PAM on one of my systems. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam

I'm using AD as my user account server with ldap.

Most of the servers run with UsePam yes except this one,

it has lack of pam support on sshd.

```
root@linserv9:~# ldd /usr/sbin/sshd 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff621fe000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fd759d0b000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd759af4000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fd7598db000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007fd75955b000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fd759323000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd758fc1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd758dbd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd759f0e000)
```

I have this packages installed

```
root@linserv9:~# dpkg -l|grep -E 'pam|ssh'
ii  denyhosts                             2.6-2.1                      an utility to help sys admins thwart ssh hac
ii  libpam-modules                        0.99.7.1-5ubuntu6.1          Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-runtime                        0.99.7.1-5ubuntu6.1          Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpam-ssh                            1.91.0-9.2                   enable SSO behavior for ssh and pam
ii  libpam0g                              0.99.7.1-5ubuntu6.1          Pluggable Authentication Modules library
ii  libpam0g-dev                          0.99.7.1-5ubuntu6.1          Development files for PAM
ii  openssh-blacklist                     0.1-1ubuntu0.8.04.1          list of blacklisted OpenSSH RSA and DSA keys
ii  openssh-client                        1:4.7p1-8ubuntu1.2           secure shell client, an rlogin/rsh/rcp repla
ii  openssh-server                        1:4.7p1-8ubuntu1.2           secure shell server, an rshd replacement
ii  quest-openssh                         5.2p1_q13-1                  Secure shell
root@linserv9:~#
```

What I'm doing wrong?

thanks.

Edit:

```
root@linserv9:~# cat  /etc/pam.d/sshd 
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
auth       required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
auth       required     pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Set up SELinux capabilities (need modified pam)
# session  required     pam_selinux.so multiple

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
```

Edit2: UsePAM yes   fails

With this configuration ssh fails to start :

```
root@linserv9:/home/admmarc# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -vE "^[ \t]*$|^#"
Port 22
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/sftp-server
root@linserv9:/home/admmarc#
```

The error it gives is as follows

```
root@linserv9:/home/admmarc# /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 75: Bad configuration option: UsePAM
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
   ...fail!
root@linserv9:/home/admmarc#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your `/usr/sbin/sshd` binary has been overwritten.

This could mean you have had a security breach, or maybe someone
just compiled a version locally and the Ubuntu version was
overwritten.

The `1:4.7p1-8ubuntu1.2` (x86) version of the openssh-server definitely is
definitely linked against libpam. It is conceivable that the pam
support was left out of the 64bit version, but that seems unlikely.

I'd try reinstalling openssh-server:

```
# First back up the current binary
$ sudo cp /usr/sbin/sshd /root/sshd.bak

# reinstall the Ubuntu version
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server

# compare the two versions
$ sudo sha1sum /usr/sbin/sshd /root/sshd.bak

# In my case, they match:
# 8a3ccd5242380674bc45b887286faa3abb51acdb  /usr/sbin/sshd
# 8a3ccd5242380674bc45b887286faa3abb51acdb  /root/sshd.bak
```

If yours don't match each other (not mine), there is definitely
something fishy going on and you really need to figure out where
that version of `sshd` came from.

If they do match, then I am probably wrong and it is a bug in
that version of openssh-server for 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: My money is on system compromise.

Comment: They didn't match. Many thanks, I'll check what happend to that file. thanks.

Comment: ...which suggests that your system was compromised, which means you probably have bigger problems than just replacing the ssh binary.  The question becomes, what else was modified?

Comment: Search for breaches on libkeyutils could be another step too: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Linux-rootkits-abuse-SSH-service-1810569.html - I know that these news are related to rpm-based systems, but you know, since they got access to your Linux box...

Comment: This morning, my sshd_config file was empty... I've reinstalled and the md5 sum didn't match for me... libpam wasn't linked, now it is...

Comment: @Maxime Chéramy, if you can't figure out who replaced the binary and why, it'd be best to assume your system has been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided in the question, it looks like your sshd overwriting may not be due to a system compromise, but due to something more benign like a sysadmin trying to change the standard ssh.  The reason I suspect this is some admin action, is that the system also has this non-standard ssh package installed:

`quest-openssh`.

You may run:

```
dpkg-query -L quest-openssh | grep sshd
```

and see whether this package contains a file `/usr/bin/sshd` which has overwritten your openssh server (according to Thedward, and also by my verification, quest openssh installs under /opt, but there's a (low) chance that it was configured differently).  In any case, you should ask your sysadmin if he was trying to replace `sshd`, by what, how, and why.

To sum up my thinking: yes, your `sshd` has definitely been overwritten, but I think it is a bit hasty to conclude that your system was definitely compromised.

Lastly: how to fix it?  Remove the `quest-openssh` package, reinstall the standard openssh, and `ldap-auth-client` which uses `libpam-ldap` support for the standard openssh.  Generally, on a debian/ubuntu based system, there's rarely a need to install non-standard, or non-free commercial packages to get open/standard functionality.  You can find more information on how to set-up `openssh` PAM for LDAP here: http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Pam_ldap

Comment: The quest-openssh package **does** link against libpam and it **does not** overwrite the system sshd (it installs to `/opt/quest/sbin/sshd`).

Comment: Thanks, this is good info.  Still, based on the fact that two competing ssh packages were installed on the system, I still suspect this is a sysadmin change and not a compromise.  The coincidence of multiple ssh packages and a modified ssh is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Does `/etc/pam.d/sshd` exist? It's part of openssh-server.

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/auth.log?

Answer (score 0):

If your system was really compromised, a system reinstall might be in order!